# Unable to read the project file ".vbproj"

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, frameworks

Recently I've encounter this problem when opening my .NET ".vbproj". Please see image below.

```
The imported project "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50757\Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.targets" was not found.
```

[image]

I've check the path and the Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.targets is existing.

Comment: FYI: You would probably be better off adding the `visual-studio` tag. You would receive more help then.